# If an NSManagedObject subclassed object is an NSViewController's representedObject is it a fault?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsviewcontroller

in an **NSViewController** subclass this BOOL returns "fault is (null)" in the console:

```
Submission *sub = [self representedObject];
BOOL fault = [sub isFault];
NSLog(@"fault is : %@", fault);
```

i do have the sub managedObject's properties, so i know that its available.
testing with committedValuesForKeys (right below the above in the same method) gives me the expected property values in the console.

> NSLog(@"[sub committedValuesForKeys:nil] is : %@", [sub
>   committedValuesForKeys:nil]);

self here is an NSCollectionViewItem, a subclass of NSViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some other cleaner ways to do this:

```
BOOL fault = YES;
NSLog(fault ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

and

```
BOOL fault = YES; 
NSLog(@"Bool fault: %d",fault);
```

via [How to print Boolean flag in NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358349/iphone-how-to-print-boolean-flag-in-nslog)

Comment: thanks, ryanjm. these are 'cleaner' ways. so i changed acceptance to your answer.

Comment: Great, but what's the answer to the question?

Comment: I'm not actually sure what the right answer is. I don't do mac dev. I was only able to help out as far as how to print the boolean info. @lulu do you remember what you found out about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't check the BOOLs value like that. Instead do:

```
if (fault) {
   NSLog(@"Fault is true");
} else {
   NSLog(@"Fault is false");
}
```

Comment: thanks, toastor. so using NSLog(@"isFault is : %@",([sub isFault] ? @"YES" : @"NO") ); returns NO for my app's setup which uses the collectionViewItem's representedObject in a binding from an NSArrayController.

Comment: Ok so your problem is not determing whether it is a fault or not, but that it actually *is not* a fault? If so, are you experiencing outdated values for the managed object? If so, have you tried letting the context refresh the managed object?