# how to print out bool in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, printing, boolean

I have set a bool value for key TCshow in my NSUserDefault,
I want to run a nslog test whether the key is saved or not, and i m trying to printout the bool value.
here is my code but it s not working, any suggestions?

```
- (IBAction)acceptAction:(id)sender {
//key store to nsuserdefault
self.storedKey = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
[self.storedKey setBool:YES forKey:@"TCshow"];
//trying to print out yes or not, but not working...
NSLog(@"%@", [self.storedKey boolForKey:@"TCshow"]);

}
```

Comment: btw, this method is for something like "Term & condition" scollview tho.  what i want is.. if new user use the app at first time, so promote T&C for him to accept, if he accepted, then the value YES will be saved to the nsuserdefault key TCshow, next time when he comes back, no more T&C view will pop up for him, directly gose to login view. thx if anyone can help me with this logic , i ll be really appricated... thx again

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358349/how-to-print-boolean-flag-in-nslog

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`%@` is for objects. `BOOL` is not an object. You should use `%d`.

It will print out `0` for FALSE/NO and `1` for TRUE/YES.

Comment: `%d` will work but remember `BOOL` is `signed char` not `int`

Answer (score 19):

you should use

```
NSLog(flag ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

here `flag` is your `BOOL`.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSLog(@"The value is %s", [self.storedKey boolForKey:@"TCshow"] ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSLog(@"%d", [self.storedKey boolForKey:@"TCshow"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if([self.storedKey boolForKey:@"TCshow"]){
NSLog(@"YES");
}
else{
NSLog(@"NO");

}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of using the new syntax you could always box the bool so that is an object and can be printed with `%@`

```
NSLog(@"%@", @( [self.storedKey boolForKey:@"TCshow"] ));
```

Answer (score 0):

already answered in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358349/how-to-print-boolean-flag-in-nslog/70104953#70104953), copy to here:

---

- Direct print bool to integer

```c
BOOL curBool = FALSE;
NSLog(@"curBool=%d", curBool);
```

-> `curBool=0`

- Convert bool to string

```c
char* boolToStr(bool curBool){
    return curBool ? "True": "False";
}

BOOL curBool = FALSE;
NSLog(@"curBool=%s", boolToStr(curBool));
```

-> `curBool=False`