# Objective-c bool true and false covert (NSDictionary)

Tags: objective-c, macos-sierra

Instead of printing 1 or 0. I wan't it to output either True or false.

Here is my current code

```
NSString *plistPath = @"/Library/Preferences/TestPlist.plist";
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSString *tester = [plistData valueForKey:@"MyKeyOption"];
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tester]);
_test.stringValue = tester;
```

Any help in the right direction will greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358349/how-to-print-boolean-flag-in-nslog

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print Boolean flag in NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358349/how-to-print-boolean-flag-in-nslog)

Answer (score 1):

Booleans can easily be converted to NSNumber objects.

`@(YES)` and `@(NO)`

This gives you an `NSNumber` object, which has the `boolValue` method giving you the `BOOL` back.